# Error while using copy_from in psycopg2 while inserting to a postgresql database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

Whenever I want to insert data in a pandas dataframe to the into a postgresql database I get this error
`error: extra data after last expected column CONTEXT: COPY recommendations, line 1: "0,4070,"[5963, 8257, 9974, 7546, 11251, 5203, 102888, 8098, 101198, 10950]""`

The dataframe consist of three column, the first and second column are of type integers and the third column is a list of integers.

I created a table in PostgreSQL using this function below

```
def create_table(query: str) -> None:
"""

:param query: A string of the query to create table in the database
:return: None
"""
try:
    logger.info("Creating the table in the database")
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, dbname=DATABASE_NAME, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, port=PORT)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    logger.info("Successfully created a table in the database using this query {}".format(query))
    return
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as e:
    logger.error("An error occurred while creating a table using the query {} with exception {}".format(query, e))
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
        logger.info("Connection closed!")
```

The query passed into this function is this:

```
create_table_query = '''CREATE TABLE Recommendations
(id INT NOT NULL,
applicantId INT NOT NULL,
recommendation INTEGER[], 
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
CONSTRAINT applicantId
FOREIGN KEY(applicantId)
REFERENCES public."Applicant"(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
); '''
```

I then use the function below to copy the data frame to the created table in postgres.

```
def copy_from_file(df: pd.DataFrame, table: str = "recommendations") -> None:
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe on disk as
    a csv file, load the csv file
    and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """

    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, dbname=DATABASE_NAME, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, port=PORT)
    # Save the dataframe to disk
    tmp_df = "./tmp_dataframe.csv"
    df.to_csv(tmp_df, index_label='id', header=False)
    f = open(tmp_df, 'r')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(f, table, sep=",")
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        os.remove(tmp_df)
        logger.error("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()

    logger.info("copy_from_file() done")
    cursor.close()
    os.remove(tmp_df)
```

And then I still get this `error: extra data after last expected column CONTEXT: COPY recommendations, line 1: "0,4070,"[5963, 8257, 9974, 7546, 11251, 5203, 102888, 8098, 101198, 10950]""` please any recommendations on how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the CSV?  This: `"[5963, 8257, 9974, 7546, 11251, 5203, 102888, 8098, 101198, 10950]""` does not look right. The quoting seems to be off.

Comment: ```0,4070,[5963, 8257, 9974, 7546, 11251, 5203, 102888, 8098, 101198, 10950]``` @AdrianKlaver, the above is a sample from the csv the "0" is the id, the next is the applicantid, and the list is the list to be passed into the recommendations column in the database

Comment: I would check the output of this:`df.to_csv(tmp_df, index_label='id', header=False)`. It does not look like it is getting the quoting correct. This:`"[5963, 8257, 9974, 7546, 11251, 5203, 102888, 8098, 101198, 10950]""` is not going to work correctly.

Comment: Is there a way the quotes could be escaped from that so as to make it a list?

Comment: Not sure. How is that value being stored in the dataframe?

Comment: Should have added: CSV has no concept of list it will turn everything into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy_from` uses the text format, not the csv format.  You told it to use `,` as the separator, but that doesn't change the protecting method it is trying to use.  So the commas inside the quotes are not treated as being protected, they are treated as field separators, and so of course there are too many of them.

I think you need to use `copy_expert` and tell it to use the `csv` format.

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm getting this error ```Error: malformed array literal: "[2837, 8561, 9174, 103057, 100075, 5029, 8414, 102145]"
DETAIL:  Missing "]" after array dimensions.
CONTEXT:  COPY recommendations, line 2, column recommendation: "[2837, 8561, 9174, 103057, 100075, 5029, 8414, 102145]"```

Comment: Right, PostgreSQL syntax for arrays uses {}, not [].

Comment: So how can this be achieved, given it is already in a data frame

Comment: I don't know much about pandas.  Does the df know it is talking to postgresql about arrays?  Could you just change the column data type to text?

Comment: @RichardOgunyale if your lists are instead sets, you will see that the CSV produced will be `{}` instead of `[]`... you may still have some other issues to work out though. In the end, using something like:

`'{{{}}}'.format(','.join(['"' + item + '"' for item in the_list]))`

... may work best for you. This should be done before calling the `to_csv` method on the frame. That way the CSV export sees it as a string, and Postgres sees it as a properly formatted array

Whether you use `"` or `'` in that format string will depend on the parameters you use in your `COPY FROM`